# how to apply 2d and 3d filters in python

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I want to find a function that applies 2d filter or 3d filter in python. the function should receive the filter function and the data.
Like the functions `filter2` and `imfilter` in Matlab,
or like the function `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter()` in python, that can deal with N-dimensions but is only for gaussian filter (and I want the filter to be an argument)

I think I can write a function that applies a filter using multidimensional convolution (`scipy.ndimage.convolve()`), but I was not successful for 1d filters. 
The code I used for 1d filtering:
`signal.convolve(signal, filter_, mode='same', method='auto')`, and it gave a different result than the function `signal.filtfilt(filter_, 1, signal, padlen=len(signal)-1)`.

Is there a function that applies N-D filters?
and if not, how can I use the convolution function?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.ndimage.generic_filter(input, function, size, footprint)` can be helpful.

Here is the document [scipy.ndimage.generic_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter) and usage [tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html#generic-filter-functions).

You can use `footprint` or `size` to design the filter range. For example, `size = 3` or `footprint = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]` sets the 3*3*3 array with current point as the core. `function` takes it as 1-D array and returns a scalar that you want. You can define `function(array)` as your customized filter.
The generic filter will traverse `input` with the filter and deal with the boundaries with `mode = 'reflect` by default.